# extract data from the interbase database tables and put them in firebird database

Tags: database, firebird, interbase

I have a database in interbase and already create the structure in firebird. Now what I want is to pass the data of some tables of the interbase database to the one of firebird.

Is there any software or script that does this? How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried Google "migrate interbase to firebird"?

Comment: Yes, I did, but no free software I saw served me. So I thought of going table to table because I'm only interested in the data of some tables, not all of them.
That's why I'm talking about whether you can create a file or something with the data in a table and then read that file and put it in the firebird database

Comment: How much tables do you have you want to pass data from

Comment: http://clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/

Answer (score 0):

As IB and Firebird have same origins, you could try fbclone.
https://github.com/zedalaye/fbclone
A compiled version can be found on Google code : https://code.google.com/archive/p/fbclone/downloads

For FB to FB copy it works. Often the tools work for IB as well. Try it.